# Troubles with my MasterMind game code

Tags: python

I need to write the code for the game Mastermind. The computer must generate the 5-`int` code, and the user guess it within 10 times.

here is what I’ve got:

```
import random

def masterMind():
   userGuess = raw_input("Guess my 5 digit password:")

   while True:
       if len(userGuess) != 5:
           userGuess = input("Guess my 5 digit password:")
        else:
           numberList = list(userGuess)
```

I'm lost at this point; if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Are you reporting whether or not a user got some of the digits correct? If not, you don't need a list.

Comment: What are you stuck on? Can you not generate the password? Do you not know how to allow 10 guesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate the random number, you can use `randint()`. This generates a number between `10000` and `99999`, so you get a 5-digit number.

```
number = random.randint(10000, 99999)
```

To allow only 10 guesses, you can use a variable `tries` to keep count of the guesses, and a `while` loop:

```
def masterMind():
    number = random.randint(10000, 99999) 
    print number # [Debug]
    tries = 1
    userGuess = raw_input("Incorrect! Guess my 5 digit password:")

    while tries < 10:
        if number != userGuess:
            tries += 1
            userGuess = input("Guess my 5 digit password:")
        else:
            print "Win: ", userGuess
            break
```